# why localtime_r performance so different when set different timezone

Tags: linux, timezone, glibc

There is one thread in our application frequently call the localtime_r. We found the thread performance has 20% drop when change the timezone from the America/New_york to Asia/Shanghai from the system(Redhat 6,). After profile, we found it is the localtime_r cause the difference.

I also do an simple test on our HP G8 server.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct tm newtime;
    time_t ltime;
    char buf[50];
    for(int i=0;i<=1000000;i++)
    { 
       ltime=time(&ltime);
       localtime_r(&ltime, &newtime);
    }
}
```

After compile and run command time ./a.out with the timezone as Asia/Shanghai or America/New_York.

1. Asia/Shanghai
   real  0m1.838s
   user  0m1.628s
   sys   0m0.206s
2. America/New_York
   real  0m0.608s
   user  0m0.395s
   sys   0m0.211s

There is no TZ env been set on both cases. After profile i found the localtime_r alway call the __tzset_parsetz when set the timezone as shanghai which cause the performance difference.

Does any body know the reason? By the way I reset the time zone on my server as 
the following. 
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York  /etc/localtime

Comment: The issue only exists on the RHEL6

Answer (score 0):

**do** try setting TZ.

Here's more about it
https://lzone.de/polscan/docs/performance-tz-set.sh.htm

The difference in your case might be something trivial like the order of the inodes of the timezone files or so.